# how to make a <select> tag items draggable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I tried a lot to search for making a Select list draggable but could not find any thing on that. Can anyone tell me how should I do it? Check this code. http://jsfiddle.net/Nj5Rj/

Html:

```
<select id="draggable" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">foo</option>
<option value="2">bar</option>
<option value="3">foobar</option>
<option value="4">foobarbaz</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery Draggrable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

by using jquery you can achieve what you want.

simple syntax :

on Javascript :

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

on HTML :

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

for the full API reference of jQuery-ui Draggable refer to [This](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)

you can download jquery-ui from [jQuery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/download/) and select what components fits your needs

Comment: i know this. But it won't work on the select tag..

Comment: you should've stated it on your question in the first place. plus, your fiddle isn't set up right

Comment: I am sorry about that
do you know what can be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiple="" title="" class="" id="anyid" name="rm[a][]">
<option value="90" >a</option>
<option value="91">b</option>
<option value="92">c</option>
</select>
<br/>

var user = 'user'
$("#anyid").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
            var name = $(this).parent().attr('name');
            var str1 = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace("fm_", " ");
            requestString = str1.replace(/_/g, " ");
            console.log('<b>'+requestString+ '</b> : user is ->'+ user+ '<br/>');
            $('body').append('<b>'+requestString+ '</b> : user is ->'+ user + ' <br/>');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4zq2/

Comment: What is this? 
how does it work?